# error with tkinter mac os logo with .icns

Tags: python, macos, unix, tkinter, operating-system

I can't see the .icns file
python, tkinter

code:

```
windows = iconbitmap("any.icns")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HTLe.png)

Comment: Please elaborate further. Add details we can use to help (such as your filesystem setup). Ask an answerable question. Include your full code. Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

The bitmap must be an ico type, but not png or jpg type, otherwise, the image will not display as the icon.
Theese are solutions

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/ico/icon.png')

root.mainloop()
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='/path/to/ico/icon.png'))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: but I am using mac os, it is not compatible with .ico and should I use .icns ???

Comment: You can convert your .incs file to png and try one of solutions.

Comment: Please be sure that you giving  correct location of your icon.

Comment: In case of being in the same location as the .py file, I only have to specify the name of the icon, for example in my case py.icns? or do you have to put an absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use `*.exe` or `*.ico` for an icon. Executables and icons work for an icon, but on mac only executables work so `*.app` should work. That is the file type you need to use, not `*.icns` or `*.ico`.